# When to want run SQL Server container, docker show sxited status

Tags: sql-server, docker

After the pulling the SQL Server's container, when I want to **run** it, Docker shows me "exited" status when O execute this command:

```
docker ps -a
```

I tried this link but it did not help me:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker?view=sql-server-ver15#troubleshooting

These are my container logs:
https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/dBBFlyulZ1Bera2caa84tA

I using **Fedora 29 x86_x64** and my Docker client version is `18.09.6 Build 481bc77` and Docker-Ce is `19.03.4`

(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: please share the docker run command you are using for the same, and I guess the next steps would to create DB and perform some operations ! ?

Comment: sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong@Passw0rd>" \
   -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 \
   -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CTP3.2-ubuntu

Comment: Try this - docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong@Passw0rd>" \ -p 1433:1433 --name sql1  microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest

Comment: I pulled the sql server 2017 container and when run it show again the exited status and that log

Answer (score 0):

This is because starting SQL-Server produces an error. 
The error can be looked up in the error log. 
Unfortunately, you can't access it, becaus the container terminates.
To lookup the error log, you need to have shared that directory...

On the host, create the location where the container stores the data:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/opt/mssql
```

Create the docker-container with the data directory mapped:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
docker run -d -p 2017:1433 --name mssql_2017 -e MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=TOP_SECRET -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y  -e MSSQL_PID="Developer" -v /var/opt/mssql:/var/opt/mssql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

(note: this maps port 1433 int he container to port 2017 on the host)
then, to start/stop the container:

```
docker start mssql_2017
docker stop mssql_2017
```

Now you can now look at the errors in `/var/opt/mssql/log` on your host machine.

Also, you can check if it works by connecting with sqlcmd:

For Fedora:

```
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/msprod.repo
exit
sudo yum clean expire-cache
sudo yum check-update
sudo yum remove mssql-tools unixODBC-utf16-devel
sudo yum install mssql-tools unixODBC-devel
sudo ln -sfn /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd /usr/bin/sqlcmd
sqlcmd -S localhost,2017 -U SA -P "<YourPassword>"
```

For Ubuntu:

```
sudo wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list)"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mssql-tools
sudo ln -sfn /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd /usr/bin/sqlcmd
sqlcmd -S localhost,2017 -U SA -P "<YourPassword>"
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan Steiger for help, it's work. i forget to make a container data store directory and mapped it